# Which documents better to provide for my uk visitor visa?

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-ties

I am currently a high school student and also part time employed in my country. I would like to apply for a UK standard visitor visa. Should I provide verifications for both school and work, or is it enough if I provide only a school verification that states that I haven't finished my high school yet? To get a verification from my employer is not easy in my case, that is why I am asking. I can for sure provide bank statements that contain my salary every month and also a document from the government that verifies that my employer has paid all social and health contributions. Would that be enough?

Answer (score 2):

To meet the eligibility criteria, you need to demonstrate that you can afford the trip and that you will leave the UK at the end of the intended stay because you have strong ties to your home country that would compel you to return.

Your school verification helps towards demonstrating a reason to return, as does your part time employment. You will need to submit proof of both, including evidence of the source of all material payments into your bank account. This typically means a contract of employment and pay slips.

Whether that would be enough is impossible to say, the decision will depend on your overall personal circumstances. However, IMHO unless you already have a good travel history and a credible reason for wanting to visit the UK as a tourist in the middle of a pandemic, your application is likely to be refused.